# Opening Realm files of format version 20 is not supported by this version of Realm

Tags: ios, swift, database, xcode, realm

I've just started using Realm as my local database for an application that I've created, I've set up Realm in my Xcode project and everything, and I've downloaded the Realm Studio, however. I tried to open the Realm file in the Realm Studio, but it says "Opening Realm files of format version 20 is not supported by this version of Realm". Does anyone know rather it is a problem with the Realm Studio or my Realm files?  My Realm Studio version is (5.0.1)

Comment: Try updating your pods, if that's what you're using to install Realm

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I've updataed my cocoapods

Comment: but it is still saying "Opening Realm files of format version 20 is not supported by this version of Realm"

Comment: Someone just asked the same thing here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64524579/14351818, seems like you need Realm Studio version 10

Comment: same issue for me.