# Problem opening my realm file using Realm studio

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I am unable to open my default.realm file in my realm studio. This is the error that I get "Opening Realm files of format version 20 is not supported by this version of Realm". I saw a similar question here in stackoverflow but it did not have any answers. Realm Studio Version 5.0.1. Xcode Version 12.1. I added realm to my project using cocoa pods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To open v20 files, you need [Realm Studio version 10](https://studio-releases.realm.io/v10.0.0).

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. So we should use MongoDB Realm Studio instead of Realm Studio?

Comment: @ZionAdams Yes. MongoDB Realm Studio should be used from here forward.